# probability of selecting cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

i'm confused by the following problem could someone walk me through it, so i can understand

> (a) 10 cards are drawn at random one at a time with replacement from
>   an ordinary deck of cards.
>
> 1. What is the sample space?
> 2. What is the probability that no Ace appears on any of the draws?
> 3. What is the probability that at least one King appears in 10 draws?
> 4. What is the probability that at least 2 Queens appear in the 10 draws?
>
> (b) What are the corresponding probabilities in (a) if the drawing is done
>   without replacement?

Solution: (a) The sample space is a sequence of ten cards, and its size is
52<sup>10</sup>

No Ace has probability (48/52)<sup>10</sup>

By looking at the complement, at least one King has probability 1-(48/52)<sup>10</sup>

There's a (10 choose 1)(4/52)(48/52)<sup>9</sup> probability of getting exactly one queen, so by compliment at least 2 Queens has probability 1 - (48/52)<sup>10</sup> - (10 choose 1)(4/52)(48/52)<sup>9</sup>

(b) Since we are drawing without replacement, it is easier to think of drawing (un-ordered) subsets, and the sample space is all hands of ten cards;

Thus, no Ace has probability (48 choose 10)/(52 choose 10)

At least one King has probability 1 - [(48 choose 10)/(52 choose 10)]

At least 2 Queens has probability 1 - [((48 choose 10)+4*(48 choose 9))/(52 choose 10)]

Comment: To be picky, the sample space is the **set** of all sequences of $10$ cards. The expressions you obtained are all correct. If they are what you wrote, there is no point in writing a formal answer that says you are in fact not confused. If you are transcribing someone else's solution, it would help to know what you have trouble with.

Answer (score 3):

I will attempt to answer with the assumption that you do not have the answers, so you can see the thinking process.

**(a) 1**

The sample space should be defined as a hand of $10$ cards. I like to use the term "a vector of $10$ cards". As you mentioned, the sample space has $52^{10}$ possibilities. The final answer is $$52^{10}$$

**(a) 2**

The sample space is defined as a hand of $10$ cards with no Aces, $A\clubsuit \space A\spadesuit \space A\heartsuit \space A\diamondsuit $. There are $48$ different draws per card of a hand. Hence, the sample space has $48^{10}$ possibilities. The final answer is $$\frac{48^{10}}{52^{10}} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{48}{52}\end{pmatrix}^{10}$$

**(a) 3**

For this question, instead of considering the sample space with $1K, 2K, 3K, 4K$...only consider the space where there are $0K$. What you can do is use the answer from **(a) 2**...simply swap out $A$ to $K$. The final answer is
$$1-\frac{48^{10}}{52^{10}} = 1-\begin{pmatrix}\frac{48}{52}\end{pmatrix}^{10}$$

**(a) 4**

To obtain the number of possibilities with $1Q$, consider this:

There are 4 ways to draw a $Q$ and 48 ways to draw any other card. The number of possibilities to draw will be
$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{4}{52} \times \begin{pmatrix}\frac{48}{52}\end{pmatrix}^9\end{bmatrix}$$

However, there are $10$ ways to arrange these draws. Divide this by the whole sample space (with no restrictions), you get
$$\frac{\begin{bmatrix}\frac{4}{52} \times \begin{pmatrix}\frac{48}{52}\end{pmatrix}^9\end{bmatrix}}{52^{10}}$$

Comment: For $(4)$, Please [see this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999242/deck-of-cards-probability-question-probability-of-getting-at-least-2-queens)